# Composer Identity request errors

Tags: identity, hyperledger-composer

i am getting an error on the

```
composer identity request -c PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1 -u admin -s adminpw -d alice
```

Error: failed to request identity. Error trying to enroll user and return certificates. Error: Calling enrollment endpoint failed with error [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 192.168.1.159:7054]
Command failed

I am using the following

hyperledger fabric 1.2
composer v0.20

the ip address of my ca container is 172.19.0.4 
so why is it that the error say Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 192.168.1.159:7054]

i have already verified (and verified) all the ca certs and the tls certs for all peers are copied correctly in the byfn-network-org1.json .
Also, the TLS is enabled in the docker-composer-cli.yaml

here is  a copy of the connection profile.

cat ./org1/*json

```
{
"name": "byfn-network",
"x-type": "hlfv1",
"version": "1.0.0",
"client": {
"organization": "Org1",
"connection": {
"timeout": {
"peer": {
"endorser": "1200",
"eventHub": "1200",
"eventReg": "1200"
},
"orderer": "1200"
}
}
},
"channels": {
"mychannel": {
"orderers": [
"orderer.example.com"
],
"peers": {
"peer0.org1.example.com": {
"endorsingPeer": true,
"chaincodeQuery": true,
"eventSource": true
},
"peer1.org1.example.com": {
"endorsingPeer": true,
"chaincodeQuery": true,
"eventSource": true
},
"peer0.org2.example.com": {
"endorsingPeer": true,
"chaincodeQuery": true,
"eventSource": true
},
"peer1.org2.example.com": {
"endorsingPeer": true,
"chaincodeQuery": true,
"eventSource": true
}
}
}
},
"organizations": {
"Org1": {
"mspid": "Org1MSP",
"peers": [
"peer0.org1.example.com",
"peer1.org1.example.com"
],
"certificateAuthorities": [
"ca.org1.example.com"
]
},
"Org2": {
"mspid": "Org2MSP",
"peers": [
"peer0.org2.example.com",
"peer1.org2.example.com"
],
"certificateAuthorities": [
"ca.org2.example.com"
]
}
},
"orderers": {
"orderer.example.com": {
"url": "grpcs://localhost:7050",
"grpcOptions": {
"ssl-target-name-override": "orderer.example.com"
},
"tlsCACerts": {
"pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nKmGQpnt/S8cCIBj0tQUH6eC4A9O9ESq2bg+z2aTz3KIU8iekQVJVw+gK\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
}
}
},
"peers": {
"peer0.org1.example.com": {
"url": "grpcs://localhost.com:7051",
"grpcOptions": {
"ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org1.example.com"
},
"tlsCACerts": {
"pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\n5UrDMBF6mWjEpLHiP3k=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
}
},
"peer1.org1.example.com": {
"url": "grpcs://peer1.org1.example.com:8051",
"grpcOptions": {
"ssl-target-name-override": "peer1.org1.example.com"
},
"tlsCACerts": {
"pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\n5UrDMBF6mWjEpLHiP3k=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
}
},
"peer0.org2.example.com": {
"url": "grpcs://localhost.com:9051",
"grpcOptions": {
"ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org2.example.com"
},
"tlsCACerts": {
"pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\n9qkKVLGC/L/opKL/mYM=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
}
},
"peer1.org2.example.com": {
"url": "grpcs://localhost.com:10051",
"grpcOptions": {
"ssl-target-name-override": "peer1.org2.example.com"
},
"tlsCACerts": {
"pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\n9qkKVLGC/L/opKL/mYM=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
}
}
},
"certificateAuthorities": {
"ca.org1.example.com": {
"url": "https://localhost:7054",
"caName": "ca-org1"
},
"ca.org2.example.com": {
"url": "https://localhost:8054",
"caName": "ca-org2"
}
}
}
```

Comment: Have you something in your hosts file that is mapping localhost to 192,168.1.159?  Can you ping localhost ?  You could also try this url to test connectivity to the CA http://localhost:7054/api/v1/cainfo

Comment: It looks like you're deploying your network to a remote cluster. How did you do the deploy to the remote cluster and how did you extract the correct connection profile from your remote cluster for use in you app?